# What is the "You have new mail" message in Linux/UNIX?

Tags: linux, unix, email, root

Sometimes, when I log into a box and 'su' to root, I get a cute little message saying I have mail (thank GOD it's not AOL).

- Where is this mail?
- What does it contain?
- Who/What sent it?
- How important is it?

Is this even actual "mail" in the same sense as email? Or is it just my system telling me something?

**EDIT:** In relation to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/306995/why-cant-i-email-myself-at-myemail74-125-235-55) question, would I be able to send myself mail using the sendmail program like so: `email@localhost`?

Comment: I have this one message in there that says "This text is part of the internal format of your mail folder,..." so of course whenever I log in I am informed that I have mail.

Comment: @GEdgar: This usually means you should stop using *mbox* mailboxes and migrate to *Maildir* :)

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/149282/safely-get-rid-of-you-have-new-mail-in-var-mail-on-a-mac

Comment: How to forward the mail: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26666/can-i-change-roots-email-address-or-forward-it-to-an-external-address

Comment: In case anyone is looking, here is powerhshell one-liner to splits that into single files readable by outlook:
`$i=0;(gc .\mail\root -raw) -split '[^, ]From '|%{$i++;sc mail$i.eml -value ("From " + $_)}`

Comment: lol noobcake :)

Comment: in my case It was cron job I created and forgot.

Answer (score 455, accepted):

### Where is this mail?

It's likely to be in the spool file: `/var/mail/$USER` or `/var/spool/mail/$USER` are the most common locations on Linux and BSD.

(Other locations are possible – check if `$MAIL` is set – but by default, the system only informs you about `/var(/spool)/mail`.)

Usually the spool file is in a very simple *mbox* format, so you can open it in a text editor or pager.

For a slightly more convenient way, most distributions come with a program called `mail` (or `Mail`, `mailx`). You can try `mutt` or `alpine`; you can even configure it to be sent to an outside mailbox. (See "is this real mail?" below.)

### What does it contain, and who/what sent it?

Most often the messages contain output of cron jobs, or a system security report by *logwatch*, or similar junk. Read it and find out.

### How important is it?

Depends greatly on the contents of each message.

You *should* at least scan the subject headers – often people ignore the mail for months never realizing that their daily cron jobs fail.

### Is this even actual "mail" in the same sense as email? Or is it just my system telling me something?

Yes to both – it's generated by your system telling you something, but it's also actual email and can be handled as such.

You can (and should) configure your mail software – the "MTA" aka `/usr/sbin/sendmail` – to forward the messages to your personal mail address. The exact instructions vary depending on which MTA (if any) you have installed, whether this is a personal computer or a server, whether you have your own domain or use a *@gmail.com*, and so on.

Note that `/usr/sbin/sendmail` nowadays is a shared API and *doesn't* necessarily mean the original Sendmail MTA. In fact, you *shouldn't* use Sendmail, but something more modern like OpenSMTPD, Postfix, or Exim4. All of them provide the same `/usr/sbin/sendmail` tool, but they're easier to configure, more secure, and just as powerful.

Comment: Good answer. Had you added links with information on how to configure OpenSMTPD, Postfix or Exim4 to forward mail to your normal email address it would have been even better.

Comment: Here's a related question that shows how to setup **mutt**: http://askubuntu.com/a/499335/75735

Comment: Great answer. But how do I use `mail` to read email? The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mail.mailutils.1.html) doesn't say.

Comment: I viewed my mail with cat /var/mail/$USER command and removed it with rm -rf /var/mail/$USER command.

Comment: @grawity should I delete the files in `/var/mail/` when I read them or just clear the text inside them? thank you!

Comment: Is this the `sendmail` which was written by ESR?

Comment: @AdamArold: No on both counts. "The original Sendmail" wasn't written by ESR as far as I know. Nowadays, the `/usr/sbin/sendmail` path doesn't refer to any specific software, but instead is a standard filename provided by a good dozen different implementations from different authors.

Comment: mail is marked as read by moving it from `/var/(spool/)mail/$USER` to `(/home)/$USER/mbox`.  The `mail` program does this for you.

Comment: It was indeed `cron` telling me something useless. Is there a way to turn off sending mails by warnings from cronjobs?

Comment: @Andyc: Make the cronjobs not _produce_ output. Use the appropriate "--quiet" or "silent" option of the program being run, or fix the job to not produce error messages by adding error checks where appropriate, or redirect the whole job's output to /dev/null like in shell (cronjobs use shell syntax).

Answer (score 275):

The easiest way for me was to run the following in a terminal:

```
cat /var/spool/mail/root
```

Comment: Best practical answer so far that actually adds to the knowledge. Now I can read the mail. I wonder why it's the bottom most answer.

Comment: I realize this is a pretty old question/answer, but [this XKCD](http://xkcd.com/838/) is relevant to the discussion. (hint: hover text)

Comment: Or just `less $MAIL` if you want to navigate.

Comment: Or `less +G $MAIL` to start at the end.

Comment: @Blackhawk And now even more [this XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1728/).

Comment: If you are on a user account, this worked for me: ```sudo cat $MAIL```

Answer (score 99):

For anyone wondering how to read these messages one by one, you can just use 'mail'

```
$ mail
```

Then type a message number from the list which you want to read.

To goto the next message you can type 'next', another useful command is 'delete'..

To see more about how the `mail` program works, see the output of `man mail`.

Comment: // , This doesn't actually work, on CEntOS 6. In that case, one must use `$ mailx`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, I need to first install `mailutils` by running `apt install mailutils`

Comment: On Amazon EC2 instances, you can install it using `sudo yum install mail`

Comment: Works for me on macOS

Comment: mail or mailx didn't work as advertised.  this answer isn't very  good, use mutt.

Comment: Works for me, thanks

Answer (score 45):

Just to offer some clarification, it's been the tradition for a long time for UNIX boxes to run a "locally configured" mailer daemon that doesn't route messages through the Internet, but only copies messages to other users spool directories (as @John T mentioned).  It is real SMTP-compliant email, it's just not routed over the Internet because it doesn't need to be.

So, if you fire up an email client (like `alpine` or `mutt`) you can send mail to other users on the system by addressing to `user@hostname`, or in many cases, just specifying the user.  You also likely have a command line utility called `mailx` that can be used to send a quick email using your shell.

Now, if you want to send messages to users on systems other than the one you are logged in to, that's where the real fun begins.  You'll need to configure your mailer daemon to recognize and hand off external email to a transfer agent, configure the transfer agent, and do a whole bunch of stuff I don't yet understand myself.

Answer (score 28):

**Where is this mail?**

Very likely stored on your machine, in the mailbox folder for your root user (where THAT is depends on what kind of mail server you have installed). You can probably access it quite quickly through *alpine*.

**What does it contain?**

Probably just some system report type stuff. "So and so tried to login 10 times with an incorrect password".. "I wish someone would run updates on me", "driver 
 such-and-such is failing constantly", "The NSA bot has boosted performance by 1%".. etc..

**Who/What sent it?**

Services on your server, most likely.

**How important is it?**

Depends on how important your server is.

Comment: I think John's suggestion that it's stored in /var/spool/mail/root is based on a (good) assumption that you're running sendmail. I think other mail servers use different locations to store mail.

Comment: Is there a way for users to use the mail subsystem?

Comment: White Phoenix: I'll take look when my mail is when I get the message again :) Is there a way for me to trigger it or is that too localized of a question?

Comment: If you want to explore running your own mail server (that people use in a typical email sense), it'd first help to know what distro you're running? Without that info, all I'll say, is that I suggest you read up on sendmail (as you're probably running sendmail already)..

Comment: Most of them are running AIX but I'd like to explore this on my workstation at home running OpenSuSe

Comment: Here's a sendmail tutorial: http://www.feep.net/sendmail/tutorial/

Answer (score 16):

`less +G /var/spool/mail/root`

shows the latest mails, at the end if the file.

Directly showing the mail file is a good idea, but using `cat` can easily go wrong. You do not want **all** mails scroll by, if there are many messages, or very long messages in the file. I just saw one with 150MB, two million lines.

If you are not root:

`sudo less +G /var/spool/mail/root`

The `+G` option is used to show the newest message first; It is not at the top of the file, but on the end.

It is an option of `less`, making it show the last page of the file  after starting. That show the last message (newest), if it fits to one page, or the end of that otherwise.

The file name may be `/var/spool/mail/mail` instead of `/var/spool/mail/root`

Comment: // , Excellent breakdown. This answer would be especially useful for those folks who don't easily know what to do with the file.

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, `+G` "causes less to initially display each file starting at the end rather than the beginning." (https://linux.die.net/man/1/less)

Answer (score 14):

This mail is typically located in `/var/spool/mail/root` when the (usual) default sendmail daemon is configured. It contains a RAW e-mail message that can be read by the `mail` utility. Who sent it can be found by running the `mail` utility and paging through the messages or reading the RAW headers.

The importance of the message usually depends on the previous factor, who sent it :)

Many system utilities will use the mail subsystem as a means of reporting and logging. Log watcher utilities and other services may send an e-mail to the local root user as a reminder about a specific event, such as low disk space or hardware errors. The mailer daemon will also alert you if it failed to send an e-mail outbound.

Comment: Is there a way to see how my mail subsystem is set up?

Comment: @Max the `sendmail.mc` file controls configuration of the sendmail  daemon on most default installs. It is typically located under `/etc/mail`.

Comment: @Max I would strongly recommend reading through a tutorial such as http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch21_:_Configuring_Linux_Mail_Servers#The_.2Fetc.2Fmail.2Fsendmail.mc_File to help you configure the mailer daemon as desired.

Comment: On ubuntu 16.4., I have `/etc/mail.rc` which is not related to `sendmail`